# With more than 95% validation accuracy in Tensorflow training model, real world performance is very low, why?

Tags: tensorflow, classification

I developed an image classification model using retrain.py with Inception V3 from google. I got more than 95% validation accuracy with training. I used nearly 400 for good and 500 for bad images. I did two training models as shown below. They are color and size of 114x114 pixles.

[image]

However, despite good numbers from the training model, I am getting around 50% accuracy from real-world images. I used a similar image set for training. When I used the same images used in training for classification, I got poor classification results too.
The training params as follows : 
[image]

I used the Tensorflow serving server and connected the client side through REST API to get the prediction results. part of client side :

```
image1 = img_to_array(image.load_img(img, target_size=(128,128))) / 255
    payload = {
          "instances": [{"image":image1.tolist()},
    ]
    }
    r = session.post('http://localhost:8501/v1/models/img_model/versions/2:predict', json=payload)
```

Current response is as follows : (no class name)

{"predictions": [[1.0, 8.76629e-16, 8.01088e-27, 1.86624e-16, 3.77703e-28]]}

Since the above method does not return  class label, I assumed its always send the numbers in the same order.[good value, bad value]: similar to how I used during training.

Any help is appreciated to understand the issue here.

Comment: If you use the inference API to test the validation set do you get high or low accuracy? If you also get low accuracy, there's something broken with your use of the inference API. If you get high accuracy, then your real-world images are too different from your training set and you should consider a different training set.

Answer (score 0):

**REQUEST FORMAT**

```
{
  // Optional: serving signature to use.
  // If unspecifed default serving signature is used.
  "signature_name": <string>,

  // Optional: Common context shared by all examples.
  // Features that appear here MUST NOT appear in examples (below).
  "context": {
    "<feature_name3>": <value>|<list>
    "<feature_name4>": <value>|<list>
  },

  // List of Example objects
  "examples": [
    {
      // Example 1
      "<feature_name1>": <value>|<list>,
      "<feature_name2>": <value>|<list>,
      ...
    },
    {
      // Example 2
      "<feature_name1>": <value>|<list>,
      "<feature_name2>": <value>|<list>,
      ...
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```

**RESPONSE FORMAT**

```
{
  "result": [
    // List of class label/score pairs for first Example (in request)
    [ [<label1>, <score1>], [<label2>, <score2>], ... ],

    // List of class label/score pairs for next Example (in request)
    [ [<label1>, <score1>], [<label2>, <score2>], ... ],
    ...
  ]
}
```

**EDIT:-** I think what you are using is Request format for **PREDICT**. I am redirecting you to the [TFX_API](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/api_rest). Please Check this link to know more about the **response and request format**.

Comment: I wish I get the result as u have shown. I updated my question with current response format I get. POST http://host:port/v1/models/${MODEL_NAME}[/versions/${MODEL_VERSION}]:(classify|regress)
 does not supported in tensorflow serving. Only "predict" works. how can I use "classify" ?

Comment: @PCG I have edited my answer. I am not sure what do you mean **by it's not supported** . The official site has examples of how to send the request format. Sorry for the late response though.